# TableView with custom UITextView cells scrolling Navbar off screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I am writing an app that has a grouped tableView that has custom cells containing UITextViews in a modal segue. I want to be able to edit the text in each of the cell/textviews. My problem is with scrolling the cell/textviews at the bottom of the view so that they appear above the keyboard when it appears.

Edit: prepareForSegue as requested in comments:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"update info"]) {
        UpdatesTableViewController *uvc = (UpdatesTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        uvc.dumpInfo = self.dumpInfo;
    }
}
```

If I use a UITableView controller everything works great - each of the cell/textviews scrolls up to the top of the view when the textview becomes the firstResponder so it can be seen while editing. But the navigation bar I added to the top of the tableView scrolls off when the tableView scrolls.

If I use a UIViewController and add the navigation bar and table view, I can get it to scroll the cell up using the UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: method. And the nav bar stays fixed. But the cells at the bottom can't scroll up high enough to be displayed.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    CGPoint location = [textView.superview convertPoint:textView.center toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
}
```

UITableView controller is doing some cool magic to make this work - all I want to do it keep the navigation bar fixed into position at the top of the view.

Comment: How are you adding navigation bar? It should come by default when you use navigation controller to push your view controller.

Comment: Its a modal segue so no navigation bar.

Comment: In that case, cant you make this tableviewcontroller as the `rootviewcontroller` of a `UINavigationController` and display the navigation controller with model segue?

Comment: It crashes when I embed it in a navigation controller.

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setDumpInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b8b9a0'

Comment: Is `setDumpInfo` a method in your app? Looks like it was getting called on `UINavigationController` rather than your viewcontroller. Probably you need to debug it.

Comment: I'll chime in: setDumpInfo likely happens in your prepareForSegue method. You're calling it on the navigation controller in which you have embedded your view controller. You need to get the rootViewController of the UINavigationController and set the property on that.

Comment: dumpInfo is a property that is being assigned through prepareToSegue in the presenting viewcontroller. It works fine if I remove the navigation controller and do the modal segue directly to the tableView.

Comment: @Bob, Post your prepareForSegue method in question.

Comment: I've edited the question with prepareForSegue

Comment: If you make UINavigationController as your rootViewController then as you see in crash log your segue.destinationViewController is UINavigationController not UpdatesTableViewController. You need to get viewController at 0th index from viewControllers arrary of UINavigationController & set dumpInfo for it.

Comment: That solved it. I've edited the question with the revised code. Many thanks.

Comment: @Bob, Please do not edit the question with answer. I have added that as answer. Please accept. I have rolled back to remove the answer from question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITableViewController` wrapped in `UINavigationController` as mentioned in my comments. That will show the default navigationbar on the screen and it will not scroll along with the tableview. `UITableViewController` needs to be set as the rootViewController of the `UINavigationController`.

Since you are facing crash as `[UINavigationController setDumpInfo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`, you need to change your prepareForSegue method as,

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"update info"]) {
        UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        UpdatesTableViewController *uvc = (UpdatesTableViewController *)nav.topViewController;
        uvc.dumpInfo = self.dumpInfo;
    }
}
```

Basically dumpInfo was getting called on the `navigationController` and not on your `tableviewcontroller` in this case.